# Why accessing a drive when it's shared via network is much faster than when it's shared using Virtual Machine Connection (VMConnect)?

Tags: network-shares, hyper-v, adobe-lightroom

I use Lightroom inside Hyper-V VM. I shared a drive using *Virtual Machine Connection (VMConnect)* (see image below) and then accessed it from the VM and imported 100 files to Lightroom. Everything was very slow. The import took awhile and then when I switched to "Develop" module the "fetching initial preview" process (sort of building thumbnails) took a few minutes.

[image]

I decided to do the same process, but instead of sharing the drive through *Virtual Machine Connection (VMConnect)*, I shared the drive on the host (see image below) and then accessed it from the VM over the network. The import, "fetching initial preview" process and all other stuff took just a few seconds.

[image]

Why accessing a drive when it's shared via network is much faster than when it's shared using *Virtual Machine Connection (VMConnect)*?

Comment: I have no idea why it's slow, but I do know that VMConnect is literally RDP over the Hyper-V VMBus, and file transfer over RDP has *always* been slow and nobody seems to quite know why.

Comment: I had my such suspicions regarding this, but now they're sort of confirmed! Thanks.